# Write to syslog from the command line

Tags: command-line, syslog

How can I write an entry into `/var/log/syslog` from the command line?

Answer (score 60):

Use the `logger` command.

```
logger Some message to write
```

There are several options available, including:

```
-i Log the process ID in each line
-f Log the contents of a specified file
-n Write to the specified remote syslog server
-p Specify a priority
-t Tag the line with a specified tag
```

See `man 1 logger` for more information on the tool.

Comment: For a more detailed `logger` example, and for remote logging via `netcat` or shell redirection, see: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/bash-cookbook/0596526784/ch15s14.html

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively, you can write to `syslog` from python:

```
python -c 'import syslog; syslog.syslog("Hello World")'
```

Comment: Honest question: what would be the benefits of using Python for this over the `logger` command?

Comment: @DrewNoakes If you're running a - python - script from the command line, using the standard library is always better than relying on subprocess and call `logger`. You already have my vote, I'm just mentioning an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess this is true for all programming languages. Have a vote on me.

Comment: just a thought - loading a heavy environment to log something to a file is not as ideal as using a simple tool like logger, especially if you want want to script it.

Answer (score 6):

As a dev, I rarely have time to closely study `man` pages, so TLDR:

```
logger -p local0.notice -t ${0##*/}[$$] Hello world
```

The gibberish in the middle will translate to the calling program. So if you check the bottom of syslog you'll see something like:

```
May 07 08:27:14 ip-10-1-11-166 -bash[42108]: Hello world
```