# /dev/log is missing. how do I fix?

Tags: command-line, syslog, virtualmin

On my machine (16.04.1) it seems that /dev/log is missing. It's probably always been missing.

The *real* reason I am here asking for help is that I am using virtualmin with csf and the `SYSLOG_CHECK` option has always failed (even when the OS was still 14.04 trusty).

This is what happens when I run logger:

```
# logger hi there
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
```

I also tried the 'python' way of doing things, [as per this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543553/write-to-syslog-from-the-command-line):

```
# python -c 'import syslog; syslog.syslog("Hello World")'
(nothing is outputted, or appears in syslog)
```

So, looking at the `/dev/` folder I notice that there is no 'log' there at all.

I checked on another machine (v14.04) and it has it: `srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Dec 16 20:34 log=`

The main differences between the two machines are that the former was a launched instance from vultr.com (using an cloud-init aware install that they supplied), vs the latter machine (which works) which used an ubuntu ISO (a long time ago).

So, to the question:
How do I go about fixing the issue of why I don't have a `/dev/log` file that some application (csf) is probably trying to write to? Note there are other messages appearing in `/var/log/syslog`, so it's all a little confusing to me.

Any help appreciated.

**Edit:**

Contents of /lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald-dev-log.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=Journal Socket (/dev/log)
Documentation=man:systemd-journald.service(8) man:journald.conf(5)
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sockets.target

IgnoreOnIsolate=yes

[Socket]  
Service=systemd-journald.service  
ListenDatagram=/run/systemd/journal/dev-log
Symlinks=/dev/log  
SocketMode=0666
PassCredentials=yes  
PassSecurity=yes

ReceiveBuffer=8M
SendBuffer=8M
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in my Android 5 device. But in my device there is no /run/systemd/journal/syslog or /run/systemd/journal/dev-log /dev/log file present in my device. And in our code base, there is no "SysSock.Use" as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you have `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`; it should be a socket:

```
$ ls -l /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Dec 16 09:17 /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
```

If this checks out, then you can simply make a symbolic link from `/dev/log` to `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`:

```
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/journal/dev-log /dev/log
```

Comment: thanks, but this solution doesn't survive a reboot... any idea why? (It works fine up to that point). After reboot /dev/log is gone again

Comment: It does not survive a reboot because `/dev` is a temporary filesystem. On my machines `/dev/log` is present and pointing to `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`. It should be created automatically at startup by the socket service file `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald-dev-log.socket`.

Comment: Thanks, that file is there... and contains references to `systemd-journald.service` and the proper paths.  If I run `systemctl | grep systemd-journald` I see that it's 'loaded active'...

Comment: It should have a line saying `Symlinks=/dev/log` below `ListenDatagram=/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`.

Comment: yes, I update the Q to show the contents :)

Comment: If I run `systemctl restart systemd-journald.service`, then `/dev/log` is created. It seems that it has survived a reboot, for some reason too (but a whole bunch of services failed: ssh, bind, etc, etc). So I'll mark this as answered. Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

For me this ended up being a problem with how the imuxsock module used in rsyslog was working with systemd.

In the [imuxsock documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html#imuxsock-systemd-details-label) they walk through how the module is supposed to work for systemd. Step 1 was where I was seeing issues:

> Step 1: Select name of system socket
>
> 1. If the user has not explicitly chosen to set SysSock.Use="off" then the default listener socket (aka, “system log socket” or simply “system socket”) name is set to /dev/log. Otherwise, if the user has explicitly set SysSock.Use="off", then rsyslog will not listen on /dev/log OR any socket defined by the SysSock.Name parameter and the rest of this section does not apply.
> 2. If the user has specified sysSock.Name="/path/to/custom/socket" (and not explicitly set SysSock.Use="off"), then the default listener socket name is overwritten with /path/to/custom/socket.
> 3. Otherwise, if rsyslog is running under systemd AND /run/systemd/journal/syslog exists, (AND the user has not explicitly set SysSock.Use="off") then the default listener socket name is overwritten with /run/systemd/journal/syslog.

The system should have falling into Step 3 and changing the default path to be "/run/systemd/journal/syslog" but instead it was remaining "/var/log". This meant that the imuxsock module would try (and succeed sometimes) to create a socket at /dev/log where there should instead be symbolic link created by the systemd-journald-dev-log.socket. In the case that it would fail to create the real socket, the symbolic link would still be removed.

That documentation was the outcome of [this issue](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog-doc/issues/397) reported on the rsyslog github. If you want to skip the discussion and jump straight to the changes see [PR#1](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog-doc/pull/427/files) and [PR#2](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog-doc/pull/436/files) respectively.

My solution was to just configure the imuxsock module to use the systemd path in my /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
module(load="imuxsock"
    SysSock.Name="/run/systemd/journal/syslog")
```

This seems to have fixed my issue and sounds like a good solution here since it would explain why the symbolic link might disappear again after you would manually create it.

If you look on your system and "/run/systemd/journal/syslog" is not present look at the "syslog.socket" to see if it is starting successfully as that is what is responsible for creating the socket.

```
systemctl status syslog.socket
```

It could be that your version of rsyslog.service doesn't define syslog.service as an alias which is needed as the syslog.socket tries to active that service.

For what it is worth I am running on an embedded version of Linux so it isn't a perfect replication of the problem here, but it seemed relevant enough to share.

Comment: I think this might be a race condition: If `rsyslog` starts before `systemd-journald` starts listening to `/run/systemd/journal/syslog` then `rsyslog` incorrect assumes the system isn't systemd and re-creates `/dev/log` as a socket.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, restart systemd-journald.service and you should be fine

sudo systemctl  restart  systemd-journald.service

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that rsyslog is installed? In my case, I had to install rsyslog to resolve the issue in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install -y rsyslog
```

Note that even before I installed rsyslog, my `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald-dev-log.socket` contained the same content you show in your post.